# What is Salon music?

Tags: piano, styles

I have read that Chopins Minute Waltz was a great 'Salon' piece. What does this mean, for music to be 'Salon Music'?

Comment: From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salon_music): Salon music was a popular music genre in Europe during the 19th century. It was usually written for solo piano in the romantic style, and often performed by the composer at events known as "Salons".

Comment: I concur with @hillin: the Wikipedia entry is a good place to start looking for an answer.

Comment: It means it's good music for drinking and carousing....    oops - sorry I thought you said _saloon_ music...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose someone ought to make the comment into an answer!

Salon music was indeed popular in the 19th century in Europe, at events which were called 'salons'. It comprise usually short solo piano pieces, which were often virtuosic. Fantasia were played, often using popular operatic themes, which were played in ways trying to 'paint a scene'.

Chopin would have been in somewhere near the beginning of salon music, and Liszt would certainly have enjoyed playing at such events.

Comment: I've also heard of salon music also being an American phenomenon.

Comment: @Dekkadeci  - do you mean stuff played by a cowboy on an out of tune piano in a bar with the tumbleweed rollin' by?

Comment: Maybe. I think I've seen American waltzes and maybe even ragtime among the salon pieces.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - I reckon that's '*saloon'*...